# Tomcat keepAliveTimeout

Tags: tomcat, timeout, keep-alive

I am seeing issues making requests to a Tomcat server. From the clients perspective it notices that the connection has been closed before it could receive the entire response.

From reading a couple of resources ([Tomcat connector relationship between connectionTimeout and keepAliveTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925681/tomcat-connector-relationship-between-connectiontimeout-and-keepalivetimeout), https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html). The keepAliveTimeout appears as though it might be the relevant parameter? It is the time that the Connector will wait for another HTTP request before closing the connection. What is considered a request here? Is this a request from the client to the server or just any traffic over this connection? Would the connection timeout in the following scenario?

1. Client establishes connection with connector and sends a request over the connection
2. Server takes a long time to process the request (greater than the keepAliveTimeout time).
3. Server then tries to send the response back over the connection.

If not, is there some other parameter that determines when the connection will close if it's pending a server response?

Comment: Do you use a reverse proxy? Tomcat should not close the connection from the moment the request line was received, to the moment the response was sent.

Comment: This timeout ended up coming from the client side. The client was closing the connection, not tomcat. Error messages in the client i was using were a bit misleading.